# Power series (representation) of given function

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Well I'm wondering if below power series is the correct result of the function - wolfram alpha doesn't give anything like the result.

The function 
$$\frac{x}{2x^2+1} = x\cdot \frac{1}{1- \left ( -2x^2 \right ) } =$$
$$x \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\left ( -2 x^2 \right ) ^n } =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty{ (-2)^n x^{2n+1} }$$

This seems like a pretty trivial thing; hardly anything could go wrong right? - well [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20of%20x/%282x%5E2%20%2b%201%29) does some weird stuff with this function - bringing in complex numbers to write down the sum function - why?

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing anything weird.  The first result is the series expansion about the point $x = 0$, which is what you wrote down.  The other results are the series expansions about other points, which I presume were determined automatically by considering where the function might be discontinuous (e.g., values for which $2x^2 + 1 = 0$), and of course, the point at infinity.  If you don't understand those expansions then don't worry about them.

The final expression which gives the result in the form of an infinite sum simplifies quite easily to the form that you gave.

Comment: Hmm ok.. I know this is off top for stackexchange, but is there a way to "force" wolfram alpha to show the infinite sum form of the series?

Comment: If you type in "Maclaurin series for $\frac{x}{2x^2 +1}$", it should force it to be centered at $0$.